# WooCommerce: Send E-Mail after order paid not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently trying to send an email to my customer after he paid for an order but the email don't gets sent:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'update_order_status', 10, 2 );
function update_order_status( $order_status, $order_id ) {

    do_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification', $order_id );


    return 'completed';
}
```

I need to do this because I want to send the invoice and the payment notification email which is adapted to this filter.

[The email I need to send](https://github.com/vendidero/woocommerce-germanized/blob/master/includes/emails/class-wc-gzd-email-customer-paid-for-order.php)

But when I complete an order the email dont gets sent.

The E-Mail I need to sent is activated in the WooCommerce settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Order completed status come so you need to use `woocommerce_order_status_completed` filter.

```
function woocommerce_order_status_completed_email( $order_id ) {
  // here add your email code.

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_email', 10, 1 );
```

This will work for you.

Comment: Nope, not working. I've added the do_action into your function but there is still no email sent.

Comment: Then first thing have you checked that normal emails are sending ?

Comment: Yes. I'm getting two emails. The first one that the order is received and the other one one second later that the order is completed because I set all orders to completed with my function in the question. Because I skip one process I need to send the invoice email now manually and thats not working. I'm using the right hook which triggers the email but I don't know why this don't works.

Comment: If you noticed at woocommerce Emails settings you will find list of emails , make sure Completed order email is checked http://prntscr.com/m41bng

Comment: Try to check with disabled the other related plugins step by step because this is working for me and I don't know how many and which plugins you used? Also check with change the theme